# Create Album and Upload Photo in my facebook account using iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad

Thanks for the help.
In my application i want to add facebook feature.
After Changes in my Picture i want to upload that image in my facebook account.
Is there any code is available related this operation?

Please help me on this.

Pankaj Gadhiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the API at http://github.com/facebook/three20 and  http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=132728